# Remove a substring in a varchar field from multiple rows of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to consult about the best way to remove a certain substring from a varchar field of every row in a table.
Let's assume I have a single column table, the column names is "user_list" and it is a varchar field that contain user names seperated by ";".
for example:
row1: james;david;moses
row2: mary;moses;terry
row3: ronaldo;messi;zlatan

the lists are not sorted in anyway.
I want to crate a SP that gets a username and removes it from every row it appears,
for instance if the db is the example above and i got as an input 'moses'
I would like it to look like 
row1: james;david;
row2: mary;terry
row3: ronaldo;messi;zlatan

I want it to be a single update command and not a cursor, and i'm thinking with myself (and now with you) what is the best way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very poor data structure. SQL has this great structure for storing lists of things.  It is called a "table".  In particular, you want a junction table instead of storing values as lists.

That said, you cannot always control how data is structured.  The following should help:

```
update table t
    set usernames = replace(replace(';' + usernames + ';', ';' + @UserName + ';', ''), ';;', ';')
    where ';' + usernames + ';' like '%;' + @UserName + ';%';
```

This will put a semicolon at the beginning and the end of the list.  If that is a problem, you can remove them using `left()` or `stuff()`.

EDIT:

To remove the `;` at the beginning, use `stuff()`:

```
update table t
    set usernames = stuff(replace(replace(';' + usernames + ';', ';' + @UserName + ';', ''), ';;', ';'), 1, 1, '')
    where ';' + usernames + ';' like '%;' + @UserName + ';%';
```

Comment: First of all thank you, but in your solution don't you assume that always there is ";" before the username?                                   because if he is first in the list the username prefix doesn't contain ';'

Comment: @matansab That is why Gordon has concatenated `;` to the start and the end of the usernames field. Each time `usernames` is referenced you will see it is actually - `';' + usernames + ';'`, therefore there is always a semi-colon at the start. Also, cannot stress enough how fast you need to get away from this table structure.

Comment: Hi, It works okay and now after Garth explanation i understand what it does but the problem is that in the beginning of the field its start with ";" and it shouldn't be like that. im trying to remove it but if you have a fast idea it will be helpful

Comment: I meant that LEFT or STUFF doesn't help me because the LEN of the varchar is known only after the replace happens fully and I cannot combine with them, right?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I took what Gordon suggested and to resolve the problem i encountered (can be seen in the comments) I did the following (How didn't I think about it in the first place? :(  )

```
update matan_test 
SET usernames= replace(replace(mail_list,@UserName+';', ''), @UserName, '')
where usernames like '%'+@UserName+'%';
```